# Create and save an animation gif inside a loop in Python

Tags: python, loops, animation, gif

I am writing an aerial robotic simple programme. The structure is shown below. However, I'm struggling to write the code for creating a gif animation and save it. How can I do it, please?[image]

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d') 

for j in range(N):
    ##### OMITTED CALCULUS OF POSITION VARIABLES #####

    ax.cla()
    ax.set_xlim3d(-20, 80)
    ax.set_ylim3d(-20,80)
    ax.set_zlim3d(0,100)
    ax.set_xlabel('X axis')
    ax.set_ylabel('Y axis')
    ax.set_zlabel('Z axis')
    for i in range(2):
        ax.plot([VecStart_x1[i], VecEnd_x1[i]], [VecStart_y1[i],VecEnd_y1[i]],zs=[VecStart_z1[i],VecEnd_z1[i]])
        ax.scatter3D(States[6],States[7],50,s=10)
        plt.pause(0.1)

### I think I should add here the animation 
       
plt.show()
```